# Right Align Xamarin Entry

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm currently working with xamarin entry control. It's residing in a grid and the size of the entry is perfect. It expands and fills the entire grid cell. The only issue I have left is where the value is displayed. At the moment it's displayed at the start, how do I get it to display on the right, while maintaining the size.

[image]

My current code

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Label Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Text="{ Binding MobileMinPrice }"
          FontSize="14"
          HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
          VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    <Entry Margin="15,0,0,0"
           Placeholder="Min price"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           Text="{ Binding MinPriceStr, Mode=TwoWay }"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End">
     </Entry>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Do you use an emulator or a real device? You have used the right property `HorizontalTextAlignment` and you should see the text aligned. In my device the text aligns right as requested in the code.

Comment: @GeralexGR Ive used both. Still same affects

Answer (score 0):

Add `ScrollView`. For example, like this:

```
<ScrollView Orientation= "Horizontal">
<Grid Grid.Row="3">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Label Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"
          Text="{ Binding MobileMinPrice }"
          FontSize="14"
          HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
          VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    <Entry Margin="15,0,0,0"
           Placeholder="Min price"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           Text="{ Binding MinPriceStr, Mode=TwoWay }"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End">
     </Entry>
</Grid>
<ScrollView/>
```

Comment: ScrollView Because Capital letters